# C# - How to chceck if external firewall is enabled?

Tags: c#, windows, firewall, cisco

We want to use Cisco NAC and need to check if client Desktop has a firewall installed. This may be not the default Windows Firewall.

Is there some Windows registry key that can be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-Windows firewalls, you can use [WMI API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655.aspx) to detect the presence of a firewall if it's registered with Windows.

```
Namespace = "Root\SecurityCenter2"  (might be "Root\SecurityCenter" on pre-vista)
Query = "SELECT * From FirewallProduct"
```

And you can use this [little gem](http://www.neophob.com/2010/03/wmi-query-windows-securitycenter2/) to detect if it's actually on or off.

For Windows Firewall detection, it's [INetFwMgr and friends.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366449%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe just check if you can establish connection, if you can't - display a message that user should check firewall if it's installed?

Comment: Good idea, but this is not the case. It has to be done on client computer.